# A holomorphic function on the unit disc is constant??

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to prove something and at some point I wrote the following:
Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ and take two points $x\neq y$ in $\mathbb{D}$. Then the restriction of $f$ on the closed disc containing $x$ and $y$ is constant as it is compact. But this implies that $f(x)=f(y)$ and as a consequence every holomorphic function on the unit disc is constant which is impossible. I could not figure out the mistake in what I wrote! Can any one tell me please?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Maybe if you posted the entire problem or put this in some context people could help.

Comment: Let's see how your argument goes if $f(z) = z$, the simplest non-constant holomorphic function: Why should $f$ be constant a compact set...?

Comment: Maybe you’re misapplying a theorem about compact Riemann surfaces without boundary?

Comment: @Lubin yes this is the problem. Thank you very much!